# How do I make the button under the image that overlaps with the Stack be clickable?

Tags: flutter, image, button, mobile, click

I placed some button and images with randomly  that I created with the stack, images makes difficult to find buttons, but I can't click the buttons. How do i solve this problem.

Widgets with numbers on them are buttons and I cannot click on the ones below the image.

[image]

I tried creating it in Stack and losing its properties. But still not clickable

```
 Stack(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 470.h,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0).w,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 2.5.w, color: AppColors().borderSide),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10).r),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: _randomWidgets,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 470.h,
                child: Stack(
                  children: RandomShapeWidgetController.instance
                      .generateRandomWidgets(6, 350.w, 440.h),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your image with IgnorePointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the item in the top of the stack with `IgnorePointer`. That will ignore all the incoming clicks to the top item.

The clicks will then be moved to the bottom item

```dart
 Stack(
  children: [
    IgnorePointer(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 470.h,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5).w,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                    width: 2.5.w, color: AppColors().borderSide,),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10).r,),
            child: Stack(
              children: _randomWidgets,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 470.h,
      child: Stack(
        children: RandomShapeWidgetController.instance
            .generateRandomWidgets(6, 350.w, 440.h),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it definitely worked